# Spectral norm of a matrix obtained by setting some entries to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, svd

For example can we say, that if $A$ is original matrix and $A'$ obtained from $A$ by zeroing some elements then $\|A\|_2 \geq \|A'\|_2$?

Comment: I'm not sure you can say much of anything without further information. Consider the fact that you could "zero" all the entries above the diagonal of an upper triangular matrix, for instance, and not change the eigenvalues at all. On the other hand, setting some diagonal entry equal to zero could drastically alter the spectrum. Is there any other information you could provide about the matrix you are working with?

Comment: @user139388 I have a certain pattern of zeroing elements of matrix but it is rather complex and I would like avoid using it. The thing I'm mostly interested is second norm. Can we do something with it, for example say, that if $A$ is original matrix and $A'$ obtained from $A$ by zeroing some elements then $\|A\|_2 \geq \|A'\|_2$?

Comment: How does one remove "on hold" badge? I've already clarified my question, yet it still here.

Comment: Just as a question requires votes to close, it requires votes to reopen.  Please wait and, should others agree, it will open again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this is not true.
Consider
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
A'=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\|A\|_2=\sqrt{2}$, while $\|A'\|_2=(\sqrt{5}+1)/2>\|A\|_2$.

For non-negative matrices, we know that if $0\leq A'\leq A$ (in the component-wise sense), then $\rho(A')\leq\rho(A)$. So if $A$ and $A'$ are symmetric, we get the same inequality also for spectral norms. This holds also for nonsymmetric (nonnegative) $A$ and $A'$ as $0\leq A'\leq A$ implies that $0\leq A'^TA'\leq A^TA$. So $\|A'\|_2^2=\rho(A'^TA)\leq\rho(A^TA)=\|A\|_2^2$.

Comment: This is almost identical to the counter example I was just going to post!

Comment: Is non-negativity of matrix elements sufficient for this proposition to be true?

Comment: @Moonwalker Yes it is.

Comment: @Moonwalker For the proof of the inequality, see, e.g., Corollary 3.30 and related statements [here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=MRB7SUc_u6YC&lpg=PP1&dq=nonnegative%20matrices&hl=cs&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, thank you very much for both answer and very relevant reference.